# Tag assistant shows Google Tag hits but nothing registers in GA property

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have two environments set up: one for dev and one for prod. Dev site is dev.sitename and prod site is just sitename. For each of these I have a separate property in Google Analytics and a corresponding container in Google Tag Manager. To do this, I followed online tutorials on how to setup GA4 with Google Tag Manager. These were up to date tutorials that accounted for the recent change from GA4 Configuration to Google Tag. Despite closely following these tutorials several times over, I don't see any data come through in real time reporting or DebugView on my GA property. However, when I use tag assistant, I can see that the correct tag is fired and that hits are registered. Attached is a series of screenshots that illustrate my current setup (for the dev environment GA property and GTM container). They also contain comments to provide further context.

[Google Analytics property and data stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvIb1.png)

[Google Tag Manager container and Google Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dQaw.png)

[Google Tag Manager snippet installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8maj.png)

[Google Tag Assistant preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9egMS.png)

I've followed online tutorials (updated to account for the change from GA4 Configuration to Google Tag). I've also scoured other forums to get an answer to my specific problem but I've had no luck.